# rename function is not working R programming

Tags: r

I am renaming the variables in a data set. I installed the required packages but am still getting an error saying that function `rename` cannot be found:

```r
(dt1 <- rename(dt1,
ride_id = trip_id
,rideable_type = bikeid
,started_at = start_time
,ended_at = end_time
,start_station_id = to_station_name
,end_station_id = to_station_id
,member_casual = usertype))
```

```
Error in rename(dt1, ride_id = trip_id, rideable_type = bikeid, started_at = start_time,  :
could not find function "rename"
```

Installed packages:

```r
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("lubridate")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("rsdmx")
install.packages("dplyr")
```

Comment: Make sure that, in addition to installing the package, the `dplyr` package has been loaded and attached: `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Agree with the comment around making sure you also use `library()`. Generally, please make your examples reproducible - it helps us to help you if we can run your code! Can you share the object `dt1` using `dput()`, or some other data that looks similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by remove the rsdmx package and it works. Make sure you're not only install the packages but also use the packages by using library function.

Code as follow:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


path <- "C:/Users/" # Your path
df <- read.csv (paste (path, "202106-divvy-tripdata.csv", sep = ""), 
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df <- rename(df, trip_id = ride_id ,bikeid = rideable_type ,started_time = started_at ,ended_time = ended_at ,to_station_name = start_station_id ,to_station_id = end_station_id ,usertype = member_casual)

colnames(df)
```

I am assuming you are working on the divvy-tripdata dataset. Make sure the syntax of the dplyr rename function is

```
dp <- rename(dp, new_column_name = old_column_name)
```

Comment: thank you @xiachuan fang, I wrongly placed column names, I make a syntax with interchanging the column names its worked.

Comment: Great! If my answer solve your problem, you can mark this question as solve by click the check mark beside the my answer.